# Add phtml to every page

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have created a .phtml that I added to the homepage through the adminpanel (`CMS->Sites->Home->Design`):

```
<reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="sidebar"  template="sidebar/sidebar.phtml" />
</reference>
```

So now I wanted this .phtml to be displayed on every page of my site and I've followed this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449832/magento-create-a-fixed-block-in-all-pages

But it does not work, my .phtml does not get loaded.
Here is my code:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Psp_SideBar>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Psp_SideBar>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <psp_sidebar>
                <class>Psp_SideBar_Block</class>
            </psp_sidebar>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <psp_sidebar>
                <class>Psp_SideBar_Helper</class>
            </psp_sidebar>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <psp_sidebar>
                <class>Psp_SideBar_Model</class>
            </psp_sidebar>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <psp_sidebar_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Psp_SideBar</module>
                </setup>
            </psp_sidebar_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <psp_sidebar>
                    <file>sidebar.xml</file>
                </psp_sidebar>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**sidebar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <default>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="psp.sidebar" template="sidebar/sidebar.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Comment: change in sidebar.xml    
`<block type="core/template" name="psp.sidebar" template="sidebar/sidebar.phtml" before="-" />`
  try this and let me know if works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have errors in your layout update - erase frontend from last file (sidebar.xml). Also I don't think this block will appear on side as it name suggests, but I am not pretty sure what you are trying to achieve

Take a look here:
http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="simple_page.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

In your case you have to change name of reference and settings inside block comparing them with example form Alan Storm's blog.

Also after that check if you file is in good location - for custom package, theme:
`design/frontend/[package_name]/[theme_name]/layout`

If you don't use custom one:s
`design/frontend/default/default/layout` 
or if you have installed sample data:
`design/frontend/rwd/default(?)/layout`

If you create custom extension you should separete you layout update from other layout files - for example put it inside psp/sidebar catalog inside layout folder (while doing it you have to add in config.xml in node  in layout update correct name of path in case of previous change - psp/sidebar/sidebar.xml

Comment: What I want to do is to add a floating button on the side of my site. In my .phtml I create the button and use javascript to move it to the side (I know thats not good practice). When I add the very first codeblock I wrote to (`CMS->Sites->Home->Design`) it works just like I want it to, but only for the `Home` page. Is there an easy to follow tutorial to create your own module that adds a .phtml to every page on your site? I looked but did not find anything that worked for me.

Comment: Try chaning type of block for core/tempalte - it is a proper type of block using a template (but in case you connect to your template Block with methods than change your type  for psp_sidebar/[blockname]

also delete output="toHtml"

also at the end check your paths to phtml and layout xml according to pointed ones in layout xml and config.xml

Comment: I did change the type of block to core/template and my layout.xml still does not work (it is in `/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/layout/sidebar.xml` and my `config.xml` contains: 
`    <frontend>`
`        <layout>`
`            <updates>`
`                <psp_sidebar>`
`                    <file>sidebar.xml</file>`
`                </psp_sidebar>`
`            </updates>`
`        </layout>`
`    </frontend>`

Comment: If you have it in your custom theme it won't work until you turn on your custom theme in backend - I forgot to tell you  - try moving it inside `design/frontend/default/default/layout' and if it works read something about setting on custom package and theme.

Comment: But I do have a custom theme enabled. Under (`System->Design`) it lists my design (`default/MYTHEME`)

Comment: I think it can be something with path, maybe package is wrong? Do you have Madision Island installed? If yes you should have rwd package, maybe thats the problem

Comment: I did have a rwd package folder but I deleted it and my site still looks the same. I think it has to be the path of the sidebar.xml aswell. When I add a core/template block with my template via the adminpanel it works. Is there a log to see which .xmls get loaded?

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates

On this page there is link to layout viewer (also config viewer) modules by Alan's Storm, you can use them to see laytout for current page. Extremely useful. For now I only have one idea... You can try insert your file with layout to different packages/themes, maybe your design setting is wrong?

Can you upload content of your phtml file?

Comment: Now that I look at it it DOES work on every page BUT the `Home` page :D

Comment: If it works like this and you have used layout xml you are one step futher . Make sure you are not adding it by cms and layout at the same time to make sure what works for you.

Also using this module - layout viewer you can check what is handle of your hompage (<cms_index_index>) and if homepage contain <default node> - you have to use following module on homepage.

Look at cms_index_index layout if there is reference content - maybe there are only right, left or someting than you have to change your reference name to existing one, for example root.